Python Django Web App Returning 404 Error for the GET request
I have created a basic web app using Python Django. Currently only one API is implemented i.e. User/GetUserName.aspx which return as simple "Hello" message. The web service is running on Django's inbuilt dev server. The API get hit successfully from web browser with URL 127.0.0.1:8001/User/GetUserName.aspx or 192.168.10.120:8001/User/GetUserName.aspx and from PostMan as well.
Now there is one legacy device on the same network which hits this API. I have configured it with my machine IP & web service port. When that device hits the API, it get 404 error.
I performed analysis of the issue and have following observations:

When I hit the API from browser or PostMan, then Django prints API on console as GET User/GetUserName.aspx 200.
When the device hits the API, then Django prints API on console as GET https://192.168.10.120:8001/User/GetUserName.aspx.
I also implemented same API in Python Flask where it runs smoothly.
On reading the documents of the device, I found that device always make https connection with the server. However, for few APIs it set some flag "verify=false" which disables certificate verification. For other APIs, it performs certificate verification.
I tried setting up https server with self signed certificate but in that case my web app don't even accept the request and no logs are shown on console.

Can someone guide me here what am I missing or doing wrong here?

Making https requests to Django dev web server should print code 400, "Bad request" error in the console log, since it supports only http. Do you see the 404 error on the legacy device or on Django console log? It seems your description is missing something. Do you have a web server in between?

Are you sure u are hitting django API. It seems from the URL User/GetUserName.aspx that its pointing to Dot Net API.

@NiltonMoura the 404 is printed on the Django console. I am currently using Django's inbuilt dev server to which my device is sending request directly.
I can access the URL from browser on my computer where Django app is present and from other computer on the same network.
My Django server is running on http not https. The legacy device is sending the http request as shown in protocol field of WireShark. However the request url shows https.

@VinayVishwakarma the API is in Django only. However, the API name User/GetUserName.aspx includes aspx at end end which might be confusing you.

What I can infer from details that issue is mismatch of http and https between Django and legacy device.
Kindly try one of these two solutions:

Move everything to https
For that run the django on https. you can use django-sslserver
to run django over https. And keep your device sslverify=false (as it use self sign certificate)

Move everything to http:
Make sure legacy device request over http protocal.
And Django run over http. check that HSTS header should be disabled. HSTS



FYI, I added NGINX server in between to route the request to my Django app. In this configuration it is working.
As far as the device is concerned, as I know it always send URL as https for both non-secure and secure communication. I can't change anything on the device except enabling or disabling secure communication.
